# Is it possible to use rows only a certain number of times when merging dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have data looking like this:

```
dfA:    dfB:

type    type | name | n
------  ----------------
   A       A | 123  | 1
   B       B | 123  | 1
   A       A | 456  | 1
   B       B | 789  | 1
   A
```

Column `n` gives the number of times an element of `dfB` may be added to `dfA`.

Is it possible to "merge" (or use some other pandas function) `dfB` to `dfA` on `type`, so that my result does not include the named rows from `dfB` more than `n` times? The sequence of `dfA` should be used to priotize which row comes first. So in this case:

```
desired result:

type | name
----------------
   A | 123 
   B | 789 ------> the second row "123" does not get added since it is already n=1 times
   A | 456         in the resulting data. The row with name="789" is added instead.
   B | NO MATCH -> There are no more rows fitting the Criteria "type = B"
   A | NO MATCH -> There are no more rows fitting the Criterua "type = A"
```

EDIT:
The column `type` in `dfA` is not the same as in `dfB`, so it is not possible to delete data in `dfB` in advance. Consider this variant of `dfA` (`dfB` stays the same):

```
dfA:     dfB:                result:            

type     type | name | n     type | name        
-----    ----------------    -----------        
   B        A | 123  | 1        B | 123            
   A        B | 123  | 1        A | 456            
   B        A | 456  | 1        B | 789           
   A        B | 789  | 1        A | NO MATCH      
   B                            B | NO MATCH
```

Comment: The logic is not fully clear, is the second B ignored because there is two times `123`?

Comment: I edited the question to include some more of the logic, I hope that helps.

Comment: then is my answer what you want? is dfA really needed?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. dfA is not the same as column "type" in dfB, please see the new edit.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not fully clear, but assuming you want `name` to be present no more than `n` times, you could do:

```
dfB.assign(name=dfB['name'].where(dfB.groupby('name').cumcount().lt(dfB['n'])))[['type', 'name']]
```

output:

```
  type   name
0    A  123.0
1    B    NaN
2    A  456.0
3    B  789.0
```

The merge operation that you expect is also not clear, but once you have the above dataframe, you can `join` or `merge` according to your requirements.